# Null error while updating the code from server side in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting null error ORA-01407: cannot update ("MGR"."MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION"."PRODUCT_ID") to NULL  while updating the record via code using entity framework but the update script runs fine in the database

I have unique constrain on two columns in the table namely PRODUCT_ID & MANAGERSTRATEGYID

If i run this code in the database it works fine. Notice I havent used the PRODUCT_ID & MANAGERSTRATEGYID with values that are in the table otherwise it would have been a unique constraint violation.

```
update mgr.MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION
set managerstrategyid = 7079,
    Legacy_Strategy_ID = 19,
    managerstrategy_Type_id = 1
    where ID = 760
```

In my server code I do the following and get error product_id cannot be null

```
var mgrClassificationService = GetService<MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION>();

var isExists = mgrClassificationService.Where(x =>
    x.MANAGERSTRATEGYID == model.ManagerStrategyId && x.PRODUCT_ID == model.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

if (isExists == null)
{

    var mgrClassficationOverride = new MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION();
    if (model != null)
    {
        mgrClassficationOverride.ID = model.ID;
        mgrClassficationOverride.PRODUCT_ID = model.ProductId;
        mgrClassficationOverride.LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID = model.LegacyStrategyId;
      //  mgrClassficationOverride.STRATEGY_ID = model.StrategyId;
        mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGY_TYPE_ID = model.ManagerStrategyTypeId;
        mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGYID = model.ManagerStrategyId;
        mgrClassificationService.Update(mgrClassficationOverride);
    }
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mgrClassficationOverride);
}
else
{
    var mgrClassficationOverride = new MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION();
    if (model != null)
    {
        mgrClassficationOverride.ID = model.ID;
        mgrClassficationOverride.LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID = model.LegacyStrategyId;
        mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGY_TYPE_ID = model.ManagerStrategyTypeId;
        //mgrClassficationOverride.PRODUCT_ID = model.ProductId;
        //mgrClassficationOverride.MANAGERSTRATEGYID = model.ManagerStrategyId;
        mgrClassificationService.Update(mgrClassficationOverride);
    }
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mgrClassficationOverride);
}

return response;
```

ViewModel

```
public class ClassificationItemViewModelCreate
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ManagerStrategyId { get; set; }
        public int? ProductId { get; set; }
        public int? StrategyId { get; set; }
        public int? LegacyStrategyId { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerStrategyTypeId { get; set; }

    }
```

Entity

```
  public class MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION : Entity, ILegacyStrategy
    {       


        public int MANAGERSTRATEGYID { get; set; }
        public int? PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
        public int? STRATEGY_ID { get; set; }
        public int? SUB_STRATEGY_ID { get; set; }
        public int? SECTOR_FOCUS_ID { get; set; }
        public int? REGIONAL_FOCUS_ID { get; set; }
        public int? LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID { get; set; }

        public int? MANAGERSTRATEGY_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
        ////public string OVERRIDE_NOTES { get; set; } need to add

        [ForeignKey("PRODUCT_ID")]
        public V_PRODUCT PRODUCT { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MANAGERSTRATEGYID")]
        public MANAGERSTRATEGY MANAGERSTRATEGY { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LEGACY_STRATEGY_ID")]
        public LEGACY_STRATEGY LEGACYSTRATEGY { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION: ID={0}", this.ID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify *exactly* what you mean by "and get error product_id cannot be null"? Is that an exception? If so, where is it thrown? Note that you've currently commented out the code that sets the `PRODUCT_ID` property, which doesn't sound ideal...

Comment: But if the same productid is gets assigned then a unique constraint violation is thrown

Comment: Just update the entire block. If you can see i am checking if MANAGERSTRATEGYID && x.PRODUCT_ID exisit

Comment: The error occurs as soon an the mgrClassificationService.Update(mgrClassficationOverride) OracleException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("MGR"."MGR_STRT_CLASSIFICATION"."PRODUCT_ID") to NULL

Comment: Right, please put that exception *into the question* rather than just as a comment. (I suspect the problem is it's trying to update *all* fields in the row, not just specific ones.)

Comment: And show us the class which "model" represents.